# How come SortedSet gives unique output without using IEqualitycomparer

Tags: c#, interface

At high level getting unique values for reference types requires implementing IEqualityComparer with HashSet but with SortedSet which is HashSet as well it does not seem to be required. 
Here is an example. Lets say we have Employee class and EmployeeComparer classes below -

```
public class Employee 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>, IComparer<Employee>
{

    public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public int Compare(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
    }
}
```

If I have to use HashSet to get unique Employees based on name it works only if I have EmployeeComparer implementing IEqualityComparer but if I use SortedSet it gives me unique values even if the class EmployeeComparer does not implement IEqualityComparer and just the IComparer. What happens to the requirement of providing GetHashCode() and Equals() method for uniqueness here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IComparer<T>` is fully sufficient for determining whether two objects are semantically equal.

If `ICompararer<T>.Compare()` returns `0`, then the objects are considered to be equal. If it returns a nonzero value, then they are considered to be nonequal. Since the `SortedSet<T>` is supposed to put the values in sorted order, it needs a comparison function, but it doesn't need an equality function on top of that.

Comment: Ok. Are you saying string.Compare internally satisfies the requirement of HashCode comparison which is requirement for comparing objects?

Comment: @LearnAndShare No, hash codes are not a requirement for comparing objects. `.Compare()` is sufficient for comparing objects.

Comment: This answer is wrong. IComparer is for ordering, which is a different concept from equality. I can have a set with two items that are not equal but have the same ordering.